# whether to go with simple database table approach or consider future possible requirements

Tags: database-design, many-to-many, one-to-many, many-to-one

This is a db design question.

There is a User table and a Team Table

`User {
  ID,
  UserName,
  FirstName
}`

`Team {
  ID,
  TeamName
}`

Now it was decided, that user could be part only one team, but our dba thinks that it is possible 
that the user could be part of multiple teams (possible futuristic requirement) and so he created a UserTeam 
table want us to implement the restriction on the code?

`UserTeam {
  User_ID,
  Team_ID
}`

I feel this unnecessarily creates problems while coding and the database tables are not constrained
according to the current requirements and we should remove the bridge table and include a teamID in the
User table and worry about the user being part of multiple teams later.

`User {
   ID,
   UserName,
   FirstName,
   TeamID
}`

Do you think my argument makes sense and changing the design later if the requirement comes really from customers?

Or is it good to stick to a general futuristic design and restrict the users to multiple teams in the code?

My arguments is for keeping it simple if it matches the requirements.
* The constraints are built into the db tables.
* In future if the need changes, we worry about it later.

Comment: Two factors come into consideration. Number one - economic. How much extra work is going to be for you to implement this new suggestion of `UserTeam` versus the default route? If not much, then future-proofing is always a good idea. However, if it entails considerable code change, then your client isn't paying for this - maybe you should skip it.

Comment: But don't you think it is not just about extra work, but one is a many-many and the other is a many-one and it will just lie around if the requirements never come.

Answer (score 2):

[YAGNI](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt).  Unless you have a compelling reason to think you might need this flexibility, don't bother yet.

Here's the litmus test: are you honestly **committed** to making this a first-class feature, starting right now?  Will you build your user interface and forms and validators and admin functionality to assume a user can be on multiple teams?  Or are you going to half-ass it and just put the capability in the database but have the code pretend it's not there?  I've been in this position, and you'd probably be doing the latter, in which case you're not really saving yourself any time—and might be wasting more of it, if you ever really *do* need this feature and have forgotten how much of it exists.

It's just code.  You can always write more—but only if you absolutely have to.

But about [that "first name" column](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)...

Comment: Thanks eevee for your reply. I was about to use this approach but after reading Catcall's approach, I leaning more towards that approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm both a SQL database designer and an application programmer.

Right now you have something like this.

```
create table users (
  user_id integer primary key,
  user_name varchar(35) not null unique
);

create table teams (
  team_id integer primary key,
  team_name varchar(35) not null unique
);
```

The following table implements the current requirement that each user can be a member of, at most, one team. (I'm assuming that some users might not be a member of any team, perhaps only between the time they're hired and the time they report for work.)

```
create table team_members (
  user_id integer primary key references users (user_id),
  team_id integer not null references teams (team_id)
);
```

When that requirement changes, and you need to allow users to be members of multiple teams, all you have to do is change the primary key from {user_id} to {user_id, team_id}. Application code doesn't have to change at all. (But see "Document the disagreement" below.)

*You* want to implement team membership like this.

```
create table users (
  user_id integer primary key,
  user_name varchar(35) not null unique,
  team_id integer null references teams (team_id)
);
```

If you do that, you should *still* implement a team members view, and application code should use the view. Depending on your application, you might need to make this an updatable view.

```
create view team_members as 
select user_id, team_id 
from users;
```

That's because putting team membership into the table of users corrupts that table's predicate. It's no longer a table of users; it's a table of users and their team memberships. So the name "user" is not accurate; it calls for a name like "users_and_team_membership". (In both the relational model of data and in SQL, table names are the names of variables, and by default they're part of your database's public API. The principle at work here is "Don't comment bad code. Rewrite it.")

But whether you fix the table name or leave it with the misleading name "users", you just turn one mess into two. "Two", because 1) one table stores two different kinds of data, and because 2) you either use an accurate name and lose the table "users" or you use a misleading name and keep the table "users".

**Document the disagreement**

You should also prevent your application programmers from doing the Wrong Thing by documenting this disagreement. A statement like "Assuming that a user is a member of only one team is an unchecked run-time error" should be sufficient.

YAGNI doesn't have exactly the same meaning in database design and development that it has in application development. Application developers look at their code and see one database. Database designers look at their database and see hundreds of programs written in dozens of different languages over a period of decades, and they count the cost of a badly written public API. Fixing a bad public API might require changes to hundreds of programs. That's a *lot* of money. A *lot* of money.

Comment: Thanks for a lovely reply. Now after reading this, I would not mind going with the first approach you mention.<br>
The way we have is 
<code>
create table team_members (
  user_id integer primary key not null references users (user_id),
  team_id integer primary key not null references teams (team_id)
);
</code>

So this somehow bothered me and I didn't want to add a "user to a unique team" requirement just
from the code perspective, while leaving it open ("user to a multiple team") from the database.

Comment: the solution is nice, but in the general case, i disagree that databases should get free passes on YAGNI.  yes, fixing hundreds of programs is very expensive—and that's exactly why you shouldn't design your schema around a fuzzy ill-conceived notion of the future.  if the actual need turns out to be radically different from the mere speculation of "well maybe we'll need more than one", now you'll have to both rip out this design _and_ add in the new one.  maybe that won't be the case here...  maybe.

Comment: regardless, this is a good reason why your database _shouldn't_ be your public API.  if you need more than a couple things to talk to the same db, build an API on top of it that can deal with versioning and backwards compatibility and whatnot.  keep all those application programmers busy and out of the dba's hair  :)

Comment: I said YAGNI doesn't mean exactly the same thing to database designers and to application developers. If I have to pick who will choose the database implementation of a *needed* feature (which is *not* what YAGNI is about anyway), I'll go with the experienced dba or database designer rather than the experienced application developer. Not every company can afford a software layer between the database and applications; the ones that can are even *more* careful about future-proof designs, especially since those decisions are usually based on long, entereprise-specific experience.